# Magento2: Get collectionFactory query in Single

Tags: magento2, collection, query

I have below collectionFactory

```
  $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('status', ['neq' => 'Disable']);

  $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['ce' => 'customer_entity'], "main_table.user_id = ce.entity_id", [
    'CONCAT(ce.firstname," ", ce.lastname) as user_name',
    'ce.email'
        ]
  )->order('id DESC')->limit(5);

  echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
  exit;
```

Above is working fine.

But when i'm trying to do

```
  $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('status', ['neq' => 'Disable'])->joinLeft(
        ['ce' => 'customer_entity'], "main_table.user_id = ce.entity_id", [
    'CONCAT(ce.firstname," ", ce.lastname) as user_name',
    'ce.email'
        ]
  )->order('id DESC')->limit(5);
```

It gives error

> Call to undefined method
>   Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Collection::joinLeft()

Why there is need to use `getSelect()`? I think `getSelect()` will get previous defined collection query. So it will carry forward that on.

We can't to collectionFactory in Single?, we have to get & then proceed further?

Answer (score 1):

Collections are an entity specific wrapper for the ORM. If you want to build a query that accesses a table outside the scope of that entity then you have to operate on the collection's underlying select.